# When to build or rebuild an SSIS project in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

is it necessary to build or rebuild an SSIS project in visual studio?

As far as i can tell, i can create a project, add packages and deploy them without doing a build or rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Building an SSIS project creates an artifact *.ispac file.  The *.ispac file is used to deploy SSIS packages.

More documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-ver15